# Strict left join from n:n table

Tags: mysql, join

I have tables: `mainTable`, `A`, `B` and `C`. 
Table C is relation table between A and B (n:n) - C=(A_ID, B_ID).
I tried following query:

```
select * from mainTable 
left join A on (mainTable.id=A.mainTableId)
left join C on (C.A_id = A.id) 
left join B on (C.B_id = B.id)
where B.type=1;
```

Problem here is if i want to get only rows from mainTable where ALL B 
products are type 1.
Now i get all rows from mainTable where at least one B product exists with type 1.

Answer (score 1):

Move that `WHERE` condition to `JOIN ON` condition to get proper outer join effect like

```
select mt.* from mainTable mt
left join A on (mt.id=A.mainTableId)
left join C on (C.A_id = A.id) 
left join B on (C.B_id = B.id) AND B.type=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have insert one left join more. This counts all products of this section and also all products from type = 1. So you can say in where cnt.count = cnt.anz_type1 to get all products if there from type 1

```
select * from mainTable 
left join A on (mainTable.id=A.mainTableId)
left join C on (C.A_id = A.id) 
left join B on (C.B_id = B.id)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT B.id ,
    sum(IF(B.type=1,1,0)) anz_type1 ,
    sum(1) total
    FROM B GROUP BY id
    )  cnt ON C.B_id = cnt.id
where cnt.total = cnt.anz_type1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
select * from mainTable 
inner join A on (mainTable.id=A.mainTableId)
inner join C on (C.A_id = A.id) 
inner join B on (C.B_id = B.id AND B.type=1);
```

This will give you all rows from maintable where ALL B products are type 1.